# Django serializer call a function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relevence = ??
```

The thing is I want to call `relevance` as a separate function.
I do not want to write it as a serializer method field nor under a model, can it be done?

Comment: Why don't you want it as a serializerMethodField()? That seems to be the way to go in this scenario

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

Comment: This should be considered the correct awnser

Answer (score 0):

Ok. do it like

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relevence = min(1,2,3,4) #user inbuilt `min`
```

But the thing is, function will execute one time only. That means when defining of class happens.